# Is there an equivalent to trigonometry for solid angles?

Tags: trigonometry, surfaces, pi, solid-angle

Intuitively I would say that it would make no sense, but this question crossed my mind :

Is there an equivalent to trigonometry for solid angles?? I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks for answering!

--

**Extracts from the comments :**

For example, in usual trigonometry, if you multiply the hypotenuse by the sine of the angle, you get the opposite segment length of a rectangle triangle, but would it make sense to define a kind of *sinus function which relates the side surface of a cone with the base surface (opposite to the solid angle), and the like??

Comment: *Solid* angles are tricky. However, there is a trigonometry of tetrahedra (what I call "hedronometry"), in which *dihedral* angles figure significantly. See, for instance, my note ["Heron-like Hedronometric Results for Tetrahedral Volume" (PDF)](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/mathdocs/Heron-like-Results-for-Tetrahedral-Volume.pdf).

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a very general question. What is the context? Do you have any thoughts on what aspects of trigonometry should extend to such a theory? Definitions of trig. functions? Trif. identities? Statements such as the "Law of Sines" for triangles?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was thinking in trigonometrical identities and functions. For example, in usual trigonometry, if you multiply the hypotenuse by the sine of the angle, you get the opposite segment length of a rectangle triangle, but would it make sense to define a kind of *sinus function which relates the side surface of a cone with the base surface (opposite to the solid angle), and the like??

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to spherical trigonometry?  Granted, it uses only one solid (a sphere) but there are trigonometrical properties that go along with it.